# Show there are infinitely many primes that are equivalent to 1 mod 8.

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

Show there are infinitely many primes that are equivalent to $1 \pmod{8}$.

Hello there!
I have been trying to do this problem for a pretty long time with no avail.

I noticed that this is really similar to Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes.  However, I can't find a way to use that here.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: If an odd prime $p$ divides $n^4+1$, what does that tell you about $p$?

Comment: Prof. Leo Morse observed that way to show there"s no largest prime is to produce a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers that are pairwise co-prime.For example.the Fermat numbers.

Comment: See also [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that there are only finitely many such primes $p_1,\ldots,p_k \equiv 1 \pmod 8$. Then consider the following number
$$
(2p_1\cdots p_k)^4+1,
$$
which is coprime with each $p_i$, and has remainder $1$ modulo $8$. Since it is odd and greater than $1$, it has to be divisible by an odd prime $p$. Then
$$
\mathrm{ord}_p(2p_1\cdots p_k)=8
$$
which divides $\varphi(p)=p-1$ by Fermat's theorem. Therefore $p$ is another prime $\equiv 1\pmod{8}$.

Comment: Note that when you said that  $(2p_1 \cdots p_k)^4+1>1$, you assumed that $k \geq 1$. In order to complete your proof, you must show that this assumption was valid. In other words, you must show that there is at least one prime which is congruent to $1 \pmod{8}$. An example of such a prime that you could use would be 17.

Comment: This is obvious, come on.

Comment: Why does $\mathrm{ord}_p(2p_1\cdots p_k)=8$?

Comment: Because we have $$(2p_1\cdots p_k)^4+1\equiv 0\pmod p$$ which gives us $$(2p_1\cdots p_k)^4\equiv -1\pmod p.$$ We square this getting $$\mathrm{ord}_p(2p_1\cdots p_k)=8.$$ Any smaller 'order' would not result in it being congruent to $1$, hence not being an order.