# Show there are infinitely many primes that are equivalent to $1 pmod 8 $.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show there are infinitely many primes that are equivalent to $1 \pmod{8}$.

I am supposed to use $x^4 + 1$ to and how Euclid showed that there were infinetely many primes to prove this, but I am not sure how. I found that 17 and 41 work but I don't know how to show that there are infinetly many.

I also looked at [Show there are infinitely many primes that are equivalent to 1 mod 8.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1399694/show-there-are-infinitely-many-primes-that-are-equivalent-to-1-mod-8) but it didn't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that if $p$ is a prime factor of $(2a)^4+1$, where $a$ is an integer,
then $p$ is odd, and as $(2a)^4\equiv -1\pmod p$ then the multiplicative order of $2a$ modulo $p$ is $8$. Deduce that $p\equiv1\pmod 8$. Also observe that $p\nmid a$
so that one can avoid $p$ lying in any given finite set of primes.

Comment: I've proven that p=1 mod 8, but how do you continue from there?

Answer (score 0):

As Angina Seng has already provided the standard technique for this particular problem, I will make some remarks so that you can solve other similar problems. This is a special case of [Dirchlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) which requires higher mathematics to prove. However, there are some special cases that can be proven in a Euclidean manner, meaning it is reminiscent of the [classic proof of Euclid's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem#Euclid%27s_proof) on the infinitude of primes. These proofs are elementary. See [Keith Conrad's survey](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/dirichleteuclid.pdf), which gives a biconditional criterion for when such proofs exist, which is that the residue squared must be congruent to $1.$ I am not aware of an easy way of always finding a suitable polynomial. In some cases, you will have to include $2$ in the product of the primes. A relatively elementary proof also exists for the residue $1$ case (your stated problem falls in this category) using [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial#Applications).